# Django session variables lost when set in form_valid() of class-based views

Tags: python, django, session, django-class-based-views

Using Django, if I set a session variable within the post() method of a django.views.generic.edit.FormView class, that variable is then available for future requests.

e.g.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Store useful data in session variable for future requests 
    """
    if 'useful_data' in request.POST:
        request.session['useful_data'] = useful_data

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

If however, I attempt to set a session variable via the form_valid() method of a django.views.generic.edit.FormView class, the changes I make to the variable seem to disappear before the next request.

e.g.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """
    Store useful data in session variable for future requests 
    """
    # Useful data that I only want to update if the form was validated
    self.request.session['useful_data'].update(form.cleaned_data['useful_data'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

So, how can I make persistent changes to session variables from the form_valid() method of a django.views.generic.edit.FormView class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem could be the update part:

```
self.request.session['useful_data'].update(form.cleaned_data['useful_data'])
```

If we take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved), the issue could be django does not know that the session has been modified and thus does not change it.

To validate this, make it explicit that session has been modified:

```
self.request.session['useful_data'].update(form.cleaned_data['useful_data'])
self.request.session.modified = True
```

Or just assign the value without using `update()`, just like in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved):

```
self.request.session['useful_data'] = form.cleaned_data['useful_data']
```

Hope it helps!